# how to save 2 texts in the same file.csv but in two differenct columns on iMacros

Tags: macros, imacros

I'm working hard to understand how to save two different text, on the same file.csv (or .txt) but on two different columns.

I've build a `.JS` that generate random TEXTs, then fill some fields and then procede with the rest of the macro.

What I want to do, is to save those TEXTs (email, password) the the .csv but in `{{!COL1}}` & `{{!COL2}}`

Is there any way to build something like this? Thank you so much!

eiifq83234

Answer (score 4):

simple solution would be just adding values to !extract - it will automatically format it in 2 different columns after save in csv file

```
set !extract username
add !extract password
saveas type=extract folder...
```